# Android emulator is not working in Android studio

Tags: android

I'm getting this error:

```
12:53 PM    Emulator: C:\Users\tenni\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

12:53 PM    Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

12:53 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have looked for similar posts on this website and tried updating HAXM to the latest version, and created a new virtual device, but that has not fixed the problem.
Maybe Android studio is not using the latest HAXM I installed?

I'm very new to using Android studio and developing apps so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT
Here's a picture of the version of my HAXM by going to settings > appearance and behavior > system settings > android sdk > sdk tools
[image: Click link to see image, I don't have enough reputation yet to embed images]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and is fixed in the latest version of android studio.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132481542

You can also try a work around by  by changing the cpu core from 4 to 1.

Comment: Ok. I downloaded the latest version of android studio (4.0) but that didn't work. Also, I went to the drop down menu in the virtual device manager, clicked "show on disk", and in the config file changed cpu core = 4 to cpu core = 1 and saved it. Unfortunately this didn't resolve it either

Comment: Which version of HAXM have you installed?

Comment: I installed version 7.6.1. But I believe version 7.4 fixed the problem? Also when I installed Android studio then it came preloaded with version 7.5.6 and I couldn't really figure out how to tell it to use the latest (7.6.1) version HAXM. If you know how to do that it could help the solution

Comment: I am not sure of it but I think you can select the version by going to File -> settings and search for android sdk tools. You will be able to view and also choose the version I guess

Comment: yes I did that but now I'm thinking that maybe the HAXM version is not even the problem anymore (I added a picture of your suggestion to original post OP)

Comment: Ok. I think the only thing that can help you is the Google developer forums right now. Post a question there and let them know your issue and also the specs of your system.

Comment: Good idea, not sure why I didn't think of that yet. Funnily enough it worked on another computer. Should probably make a post to the google issue tracker